# Mongodb PHP updated document passed as a parameter through ajax does not save

Tags: ajax, json, mongodb, save, parameter-passing

I am having a problem with MongoDB using PHP and Javascript.

1) I write out a document to the collection and verify it is there.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("500d9f072d854e2001000018"),
  "field1": "happenstance",
  "mydata": "balls  grinders",
  "desc": "johnsig"
```

}

2) Using javascript I fetch the record from the collection by calling a php program.

```
function fetch(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "sbugger.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "mode=fetch",
    success: function(data){        
        record = data;
    }
});
```

}

3) I modify the "desc" element and save the document by passing it back to the php program

```
function save(){
record.desc=" HELLO THERE FELLA";
jString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(record));
myData =  "mode=save&record="+jString;
url = "sbugger.php";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData,
    success: function(data){
        document.write(data);
        }   });

}
```

On the php side the code is:

```
 $stuff = json_decode($_REQUEST["record"],true);  
 $collection->save($stuff);

 var_dump($stuff);
 var_dump($db->lastError());
```

Because I did not modify the $id I assume that 
this would simply update the record in place.

Instead I get this var_dump:

```
  object(stdClass)[4]
  public '_id' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
  public '$id' => string '500d9f072d854e2001000018' (length=24)
  public 'field1' => string 'happenstance' (length=12)
  public 'mydata' => string 'balls  grinders' (length=15)
  public 'desc' => string ' HELLO THERE FELLA' (length=18)
```

and this lastError msg

array
      'err' => string 'invalid operator: $id' (length=21)
      'code' => int 10068
      'n' => int 0
     'lastOp' => 
        object(MongoTimestamp)[8]
          public 'sec' => int 1343070014
          public 'inc' => int 1
      'connectionId' => int 56143
       'ok' => float 1

I have been beating my head against the wall with this for 1.5 days.

Can any MongoDB gurus please help me?

P.S. If I remain solely in a php program the find and save work perfectly.
It seems when passing json back and forth there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

By transforming your Mongo document from PHP to JSON and back, you lost type information for the `_id` field. In MongoDB's native BSON, this is an [object ID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs). PHP represents the same type as a [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) object and Mongo's JS shell uses an ObjectId class. In pure JSON, there is no class information, so this is represented as an object with a string as its only `$id` property. The error message you saw is because `$id` is being interpreted as a query operator.

Although this came up with the ID field, you can expect to see the same loss of type information when dealing with other BSON types (e.g. dates, timestamps, regex patterns). To immediately resolve this, you can manually convert fields to the classes provided by the PHP driver.

Alternatively, I'd say there's really no reason to pass the entire document back for writing. I would suggest researching backbone.js, which provides [change detection](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) for model attributes. That would allow you to model your documents in the frontend, minimize the data sent back to the server, and take advantage of atomic updates (`$set` operations) when updating the document in Mongo.